# Put Hashmap into Arraylist<HashMap>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I'm new at android. I trying to get the data from `Database` and put it into `HashMap`. But I got a little problem here. I got an error when I try to put the data that I get.

I put a comment on the error line in my code. You can check it below

Here's my class

```
private static final String TAG_ITEM_NAME = "item_name";
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchlist;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    searchlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Intent search = getIntent();
    String searchResult = search.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(

    List <AllItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AllItem>();

    allItems = db.getAllSearchResult(searchResult);

    HashMap<String, AllItem> all_Items = new HashMap<String, AllItem>();

    for(AllItem cn : allItems) {    


        String item_name = cn.getItem_name();
        //AllItem item_name = all_Items.put(cn.getItem_name(), cn);

        all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME,item_name);  // I got error here
    }

    searchlist.add(all_Items);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            Search.this, searchlist,
            R.layout.searchlayout, new String[] {TAG_ITEM_NAME}, 
            new int[] { R.id.category_name}
            );

 // Assign adapter to ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

The error said `The Method put(String, Allitem) int type Hashmap<String,Allitem> is not applicable for the argument (String, String)`

How to fix this error? Thanks before :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all_Items` is defined as a hashmap to contain `<String, AllItem>` key value  pairs as defined here:

```
HashMap<String, AllItem> all_Items = new HashMap<String, AllItem>();
```

but you are trying to push `<String,String>` key value pair into your `all_Items` hashmap :

```
all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME,item_name);  // I got error here
```

It seems you want to push the `AllItem` object against its `item_name`, which can be done as:

```
all_Items.put(item_name, cn);
```

Comment: Thanks. But why when I change the all values `HashMap` into AllItem and do the search I got nothing?

Answer (score 1):

all_items takes a `String` and an `AllItem`, but you are placing two `String`s into it in this line:

```
// TAG_ITEM_NAME is a String and item_name is also a String
all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME,item_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to put in the map as a value string but you map expect as a value AllItem, so you must modify your code in this way:

```
for(AllItem cn : allItems) {    
    String item_name = cn.getItem_name();
    all_Items.put(item_name , cn );
}
```

This code will add your class object to the map with the key which equals to your object name.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HashMap` is as follows:

```
HashMap<String, AllItem> all_Items = new HashMap<String, AllItem>();
```

This means it has `String` keys and `AllItem` values. You can put a `AllItem` object inside this `HashMap`.

When you write

```
all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME,item_name);  // I got error here
```

you are putting a `String` inside the `HashMap` hence it is giving error.

You should be doing:

```
 all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME,cn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hashmap is `<String, Allitem>`. While you try to put `<String, String>` in it.

```
all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME, item_name);
```

should be changed to

```
all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME, cn);
```

Hope you got the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see connection in the code but using the given information, your error probably is related to your `searchlist` variable in your code.

change this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchlist;
```

to this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, AllItem>> searchlist;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you declared `HashMap<String, AllItem>` and you try to put`all_Items.put(TAG_ITEM_NAME,item_name); which would probably be HashMap<String, String>()`.